# Parse and semantic issues compiling a simple hello world file

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I use xcode 4, I already compiled Cocoa applictions without problems, but if I choose to compile a simple command line tool like this one:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

I get a lot of parse and sematic issues:

[image: _Issues_]

[image]

If this isn't enough I could take the screen of the whole window.
So what could be the reason of these errors?

Comment: Which frameworks does your command-line tool link against?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You named your main file as `main.cpp`. That's a C++ file. You then handed it Objective-C. Your main file should be `main.m`.